# Integrating by substitution containing a further factor problem

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

The problem:

$$ {\int } (x+1)(3x+1)^9  dx $$

let *u* = 3 *x* +1

3 *x* = *u* - 1

$ x = \frac{1}{3} (u-1) $

Hence,

$ x + 1 = \frac{1}{3} (u-1) + 1$

$  = \frac{1}{3} (u+2) $  This line here I do not understand.

The + 1 become a 3? How does this happen?

Comment: If you distribute the $1/3$, you might notice why it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
x+1=\frac{1}{3}(u-1)+1 \quad \iff \quad x+1=\frac{1}{3}u -\frac{1}{3}+1=\frac{1}{3}u+\frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. I don't know how I missed that for a while. Much appreciated.